# Как из списка двоичных элементов вернуть список десятичных чисел?

Tags: python

```
# Имеется исходный список 'a' с цифрами от 1 до 9 (в десятичной системе счисления)
a = [i for i in range(1,10)]
print(a)

# Имеется список 'b' с цифрами от 1 до 9 (в двоичной системе счисления)
b = [bin(i) for i in a]
print(b)

# Какую функцию необходимо применить со списком 'b' (список 'a' использовать нельзя!!!), 
# чтобы обратно вернуть  список 'a' с цифрами от 1 до 9
# (в десятичной системе счисления)

# Если это возможно, то без БИБЛИОТЕК (NO IMPORT).
```

Comment: Задание некорректное. "цифрами от 1 до 9 (в двоичной системе счисления)" - в двоичной системе всего две цифры - 0 и 1 :) видимо, писавший задание не понимает разницы между цифрами и числами

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Вопрос закрыт.
"с цифрами от 1 до 9 (в двоичной системе счисления)" - НЕВЕРНАЯ ФОРМУЛИРОВКА 
(вместо цифр числа)
В двоичной системе две цифры : 0 и 1. С замечанием согласен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например:

```
print([int(x[2:],2) for x in b])
```

Хоть и учебная задача, но тут невозможно догадаться, если не знать, что `int` принимает параметром систему счисления. Это только знать.

Comment: Что означает число 2 после запятой?
А разве в  `int()` может принимать больше двух аргументов?

Comment: @Iluhensun https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int

Comment: @Iluhensun Так это и есть основание системы счисления - двоичная.